# How to export a function from other file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two files:

**myService.js**

```
const Period= require('./period');
const myService = module.exports = {};

const defaults = {
    heating: new Period('heating', 'Oct', 15, 'Mar', 1),
    cooling: new Period('cooling', 'Apr', 15, 'Sep', 15)
};

const periods = {
    AustraliaDefault: {
        heating: new Period('heating', 'Jul', 1, 'Aug', 31), 
        cooling: new Period('cooling', 'Sep', 1, 'Mar', 1)
    }
};

myService.getPeriod = function (site, key) {
    return Promise.all([
        myService.findHeat(site, key),
        myService.findCool(site, key)
    ]).spread(function (heating, cooling) {
        return { heating: heating, cooling: cooling };
    });
};

myService.findHeat = function (site, key) {
    return Promise.resolve(periods[key] && periods[key]['heating'] || defaults['heating']);
};
myService.findingCoolingSeason = function (site, key) {
    return Promise.resolve(periods[key] && periods[key]['cooling'] || defaults['cooling']);
};
```

and **Breakdown.js**

```
...
const myService = require('./myService');
...

check('no use of heating during summer', function (report) {
    const model = report.findSection('Breakdown').model;
    const heatingSeries = _.findWhere(model.series, { name: 'Space heating' });
    if (!heatingSeries || model.series.length === 1) {
        return;
    }

    const totalAccounts = _.size(report.asModel().accountNumbers);
    const warnings = _.compact(_.map(['May', 'Jun'], function (monthLabel) {
        const summerIndex = _.indexOf(model.xAxis, monthLabel);
        const heatingSummerCost = heatingSeries.data[summerIndex];
        if (heatingSummerCost > (totalAccounts * maxSum)) {
            return {
                month: monthLabel,
                cost: heatingSummerCost,
                accounts: totalAccounts
            };
        }
    }));
    this.should(!warnings.length, util.format('breakdown chart indicates heating (%s) in summer (%s) in %d account(s)', _.pluck(warnings, 'cost'), _.pluck(warnings, 'month'), totalAccounts));
}),
```

The first file must describe the seasons(summer, winter) which are different between northern and southern hemisphere.
I must call somehow **myService** in **Breakdown** . If it is let as default, it will detect that there is use of heating in summer (because in default in takes the northern hemisphere seasons) but it must be able to check for which one to compute it.

What I've tried is to import myService into Breakdown and instead of mapping `['May', 'Jun']` to use `myService.findHeat` or `myService.Seasons` and others but it doesn't work. It lets them as `undefined` no matter what method I use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is exporting not working for you? its a common use afaik

Comment: I'm not sure, but any method I tried to use `myService` in `Breakdown` I got `undefined`.

Comment: can you add a code snippet showing how you use `myService`?

Comment: In the second file after the `//TODO comment`: `const warnings = _.compact(_.map(myService.findingHeatingSeason(site, cohortKey), function (monthLabel)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't added the following line to myService.js if you haven't already.

```
exports.myService = myService
```

EDIT

try removing,

```
const myService = module.exports = {};
```

and adding,

```
exports.myService = myService
```

At the bottom.

**Update**

If you want to use it as a module try something like,

```
module.exports = {
  sayHelloInEnglish: function() {
    return "HELLO";
  },

  sayHelloInSpanish: function() {
    return "Hola";
  }
};
```

Comment: Isn't this doing the same? `const myService = module.exports = {};`

Comment: try the edit, might be because it's  exporting empty object before modification. I might be swinging wildly though :D

Comment: @migea Module export sample added in update as well.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your issue is the line

```
const myService = module.exports = {};
```

what you are doing here is the equivalent to

```
const myService = {};
module.exports = {};
myService.someFunction = function() {...}
console.dir(myService) // output {someFunction:function(){}}
console.dir(require('./my-service')) //output {}
```

So the module you are exporting will be an object with no attributes.  You need to move the module.exports

```
const myService = {};
```

Then after all your code use

```
module.exports = myService;
```

In the context of your code

```
const Season = require('./season');
const myService = {};

const defaults = {
    heating: new Season('heating', 'October', 15, 'March', 1),
    cooling: new Season('cooling', 'April', 15, 'September', 15)
};

const seasons = {
    AustraliaDefault: {
        heating: new Season('heating', 'July', 1, 'August', 31), 
        cooling: new Season('cooling', 'September', 1, 'March', 1)
    }
};

myService.gettingSeasonalityAnalysis = function (site, cohortKey) {
    return Promise.all([
        myService.findingHeatingSeason(site, cohortKey),
        myService.findingCoolingSeason(site, cohortKey)
    ]).spread(function (heating, cooling) {
        return { heating: heating, cooling: cooling };
    });
};

myService.findingHeatingSeason = function (site, cohortKey) {
    return Promise.resolve(seasons[cohortKey] && seasons[cohortKey]['heating'] || defaults['heating']);
};
myService.findingCoolingSeason = function (site, cohortKey) {
    return Promise.resolve(seasons[cohortKey] && seasons[cohortKey]['cooling'] || defaults['cooling']);
};

module.exports = myService;
```

I created a glitch to show this working in an api:
https://ubiquitous-seer.glitch.me/findingCoolingSeason

You can edit the code here to play around with it:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/e6f80fed-05b7-45de-8366-64fb2f13bd6d

Here is a read only view:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ubiquitous-seer

You need to remember that you are using Promises so remember to use .then when calling the function

Comment: see above, I've updated to include an example of how you could use the myService within breakdown.  Feel free to edit